# Entity Framework: DbContext ¿Que es?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

como definen de una manera facil de entender lo que es y que se hace con un `DbContext` de **EntityFramework**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Human80IQ El `DbContext` es el modo que Entity entiende que tablas estas usando en tu base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
    [Table("tuTabla")]
        public class TablaEntity
        {
            [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
            [Required]
            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Ingresar Un Nombre.")]
            [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "{0} la longitud debe estar entre {2} y {1}.", MinimumLength = 4)]
            [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
            public string NOMBRE { get; set; }


            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Ingresar Un Valor.")]
            [Range(1, 100000)]
            [Display(Name = "Valor")]
            public int VALOR { get; set; }
```

Este es un ejemplo de un modelo para Entity, es decir lo que sera una tabla, cuando estas en un controlador, tú `dbContext` se encargara de invocar los datos por medio del modelo tratarlos en el controlador y mostrarlos en tú vista claro esta si utilizas `MVC`.

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

`DbContext` es la clase primaria responsable de interactuar con la base de datos.

Es responsable de las siguientes actividades:

**Consulta**: Convierte consultas `LINQ-to-Entities` en consultas `SQL` y las envía a la base de datos.

**Seguimiento de cambios** : realiza un seguimiento de los cambios que ocurrieron en las entidades después de consultar desde la base de datos.

**Datos persistentes**: realiza las operaciones Insertar, Actualizar y Eliminar en la base de datos, en función de los estados de la entidad.

**Almacenamiento en caché**: proporciona almacenamiento en caché de primer nivel de forma predeterminada. Almacena las entidades que se han recuperado durante el tiempo de vida de una clase de contexto.

**Gestionar relaciones:** gestiona relaciones utilizando `CSDL`, `MSL` y `SSDL` en el enfoque `Db-First` o `Model-First`, y utilizando configuraciones de API fluidas en el enfoque `Code-First.`

**Materialización de objetos:** Convierte datos sin procesar de la base de datos en objetos de entidad.